# Have underscore shortcut on the first letter by default

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have some buttons and shortcuts that have text such as "&Pushbutton". These shortcuts are only displayed if the alt key is pressed.I wanted to know if there was a way for me to have them display by default without the need for the user to press the alt key.
I did try doing something like this

```
extern void qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic(bool b);

void someclass::somemethod()
{
    qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic(true);
}
```

However that does not help also.I am using Qt 5 and windows 7

Comment: Many text widgets in Qt can be formatted with HTML-style formatting. Try using `<u>P</u>ushbutton`.

Comment: Cornstalks: QPushButton doesn't support rich text.